# Giving different users different Permissions on database

Tags: sql-server, database

I have a table containing my user (Admins) and another table for other accounts.
each of these accounts are in a accountsgroup table.

I want to give a list of accountsgroups access to a user. This access is different for each user.

Something like this:

Users:

1. user1
2. user2

accountsGroups:

1. group1
2. group2
3. group3
4. group4

   - user1 has access to group1 and group2
   - user2 has access to group1 and group3

How to give them these permissions?

Do I have to add another table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to solve your problem is to add a third table.
This table is sometimes called an "associative table", or "association table".
It can look a bit like this: useraccountgroups = { id, user, group }.
The records, then, will look like this: (1, "user1", "group1"), (2, "user1", "group2").

Hope this helps.